# Kivy app on android gives "IsADirectoryError" error when connecting to Azure table

Tags: python, android, python-3.x, kivy

I am building a small kivy android app which reads/writes data to Azure table. My app is working fine in windows 10 system. However in my android device, it gives me below error:

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
07-09 01:10:27.476 13592 13651 I python  :    File "/home/vimis/testapp/.buildozer/android/app/main.py", line 161, in <module>
07-09 01:10:27.477 13592 13651 I python  :    File "/home/vimis/testapp/.buildozer/android/platform/build-arm64-v8a_armeabi-v7a/build/python-installs/testchamp/arm64-v8a/kivy/app.py", line 956, in run
07-09 01:10:27.478 13592 13651 I python  :    File "/home/vimis/testapp/.buildozer/android/platform/build-arm64-v8a_armeabi-v7a/build/python-installs/testchamp/arm64-v8a/kivy/base.py", line 574, in runTouchApp
07-09 01:10:27.478 13592 13651 I python  :    File "/home/vimis/testapp/.buildozer/android/platform/build-arm64-v8a_armeabi-v7a/build/python-installs/testchamp/arm64-v8a/kivy/base.py", line 339, in mainloop
07-09 01:10:27.479 13592 13651 I python  :    File "/home/vimis/testapp/.buildozer/android/platform/build-arm64-v8a_armeabi-v7a/build/python-installs/testchamp/arm64-v8a/kivy/base.py", line 383, in idle
07-09 01:10:27.480 13592 13651 I python  :    File "/home/vimis/testapp/.buildozer/android/platform/build-arm64-v8a_armeabi-v7a/build/python-installs/testchamp/arm64-v8a/kivy/base.py", line 334, in dispatch_input
07-09 01:10:27.480 13592 13651 I python  :    File "/home/vimis/testapp/.buildozer/android/platform/build-arm64-v8a_armeabi-v7a/build/python-installs/testchamp/arm64-v8a/kivy/base.py", line 263, in post_dispatch_input
07-09 01:10:27.481 13592 13651 I python  :    File "kivy/_event.pyx", line 731, in kivy._event.EventDispatcher.dispatch
07-09 01:10:27.482 13592 13651 I python  :    File "/home/vimis/testapp/.buildozer/android/platform/build-arm64-v8a_armeabi-v7a/build/python-installs/testchamp/arm64-v8a/kivy/core/window/__init__.py", line 1691, in on_motion
07-09 01:10:27.482 13592 13651 I python  :    File "kivy/_event.pyx", line 731, in kivy._event.EventDispatcher.dispatch
07-09 01:10:27.483 13592 13651 I python  :    File "/home/vimis/testapp/.buildozer/android/platform/build-arm64-v8a_armeabi-v7a/build/python-installs/testchamp/arm64-v8a/kivy/core/window/__init__.py", line 1708, in on_touch_down
07-09 01:10:27.484 13592 13651 I python  :    File "kivy/_event.pyx", line 731, in kivy._event.EventDispatcher.dispatch
07-09 01:10:27.484 13592 13651 I python  :    File "/home/vimis/testapp/.buildozer/android/platform/build-arm64-v8a_armeabi-v7a/build/python-installs/testchamp/arm64-v8a/kivy/uix/screenmanager.py", line 1210, in on_touch_down
07-09 01:10:27.485 13592 13651 I python  :    File "/home/vimis/testapp/.buildozer/android/platform/build-arm64-v8a_armeabi-v7a/build/python-installs/testchamp/arm64-v8a/kivy/uix/widget.py", line 589, in on_touch_down
07-09 01:10:27.485 13592 13651 I python  :    File "kivy/_event.pyx", line 731, in kivy._event.EventDispatcher.dispatch
07-09 01:10:27.486 13592 13651 I python  :    File "/home/vimis/testapp/.buildozer/android/platform/build-arm64-v8a_armeabi-v7a/build/python-installs/testchamp/arm64-v8a/kivy/uix/relativelayout.py", line 306, in on_touch_down
07-09 01:10:27.486 13592 13651 I python  :    File "/home/vimis/testapp/.buildozer/android/platform/build-arm64-v8a_armeabi-v7a/build/python-installs/testchamp/arm64-v8a/kivy/uix/widget.py", line 589, in on_touch_down
07-09 01:10:27.487 13592 13651 I python  :    File "kivy/_event.pyx", line 731, in kivy._event.EventDispatcher.dispatch
07-09 01:10:27.487 13592 13651 I python  :    File "/home/vimis/testapp/.buildozer/android/platform/build-arm64-v8a_armeabi-v7a/build/python-installs/testchamp/arm64-v8a/kivy/uix/widget.py", line 589, in on_touch_down
07-09 01:10:27.488 13592 13651 I python  :    File "kivy/_event.pyx", line 731, in kivy._event.EventDispatcher.dispatch
07-09 01:10:27.488 13592 13651 I python  :    File "/home/vimis/testapp/.buildozer/android/platform/build-arm64-v8a_armeabi-v7a/build/python-installs/testchamp/arm64-v8a/kivy/uix/behaviors/button.py", line 151, in on_touch_down
07-09 01:10:27.489 13592 13651 I python  :    File "kivy/_event.pyx", line 727, in kivy._event.EventDispatcher.dispatch
07-09 01:10:27.490 13592 13651 I python  :    File "kivy/_event.pyx", line 1307, in kivy._event.EventObservers.dispatch
07-09 01:10:27.490 13592 13651 I python  :    File "kivy/_event.pyx", line 1191, in kivy._event.EventObservers._dispatch
07-09 01:10:27.491 13592 13651 I python  :    File "/home/vimis/testapp/.buildozer/android/platform/build-arm64-v8a_armeabi-v7a/build/python-installs/testchamp/arm64-v8a/kivy/lang/builder.py", line 55, in custom_callback
07-09 01:10:27.491 13592 13651 I python  :    File "/data/data/org.test.testchamp/files/app/worldchamp.kv", line 32, in <module>
07-09 01:10:27.493 13592 13651 I python  :      on_press: root.on_next(self)
07-09 01:10:27.493 13592 13651 I python  :    File "/home/vimis/testapp/.buildozer/android/app/main.py", line 48, in on_next
07-09 01:10:27.494 13592 13651 I python  :    File "/home/vimis/testapp/.buildozer/android/platform/build-arm64-v8a_armeabi-v7a/build/python-installs/testchamp/arm64-v8a/azure/data/tables/_table_service_client.py", line 97, in from_connection_string
07-09 01:10:27.494 13592 13651 I python  :    File "/home/vimis/testapp/.buildozer/android/platform/build-arm64-v8a_armeabi-v7a/build/python-installs/testchamp/arm64-v8a/azure/data/tables/_base_client.py", line 228, in __init__
07-09 01:10:27.494 13592 13651 I python  :    File "/home/vimis/testapp/.buildozer/android/platform/build-arm64-v8a_armeabi-v7a/build/python-installs/testchamp/arm64-v8a/azure/data/tables/_base_client.py", line 141, in __init__
07-09 01:10:27.494 13592 13651 I python  :    File "/home/vimis/testapp/.buildozer/android/platform/build-arm64-v8a_armeabi-v7a/build/python-installs/testchamp/arm64-v8a/azure/data/tables/_base_client.py", line 248, in _configure_policies
07-09 01:10:27.495 13592 13651 I python  :    File "/home/vimis/testapp/.buildozer/android/platform/build-arm64-v8a_armeabi-v7a/build/python-installs/testchamp/arm64-v8a/azure/core/pipeline/policies/_universal.py", line 227, in __init__
07-09 01:10:27.495 13592 13651 I python  :    File "/home/vimis/testapp/.buildozer/android/platform/build-arm64-v8a_armeabi-v7a/build/other_builds/python3/arm64-v8a__ndk_target_21/python3/Lib/platform.py", line 1224, in platform
07-09 01:10:27.495 13592 13651 I python  :    File "/home/vimis/testapp/.buildozer/android/platform/build-arm64-v8a_armeabi-v7a/build/other_builds/python3/arm64-v8a__ndk_target_21/python3/Lib/platform.py", line 196, in libc_ver
07-09 01:10:27.495 13592 13651 I python  :  IsADirectoryError: [Errno 21] Is a directory: '/data/data/org.test.testchamp/files/app'
07-09 01:10:27.496 13592 13651 I python  : Python for android ended.
```

I have a simple button which calls on_next:

```
Screen:
        name: "scrn_1"
        BoxLayout:
            orientation: "vertical"
            padding: [20,20,20,20]
            spacing: 20
            Button:            
                text: "Click Me"
                on_press: root.on_next(self)
```

And in this method I am creating table object:

```
    def on_next(self, obj):
        self.table_name = "text"

        self.ids.bx_input.clear_widgets()
        self.ids.btn_guess.disabled = False
        connection_str = "*****"
        service_client = TableServiceClient.from_connection_string(conn_str=connection_str)
        table_client = service_client.get_table_client(self.table_name)
```

I am not sure about the error. Any help.

Comment: Just updating the comment as I couldn't find any solution so switched to REST api for Azure Tables.